# NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to make this query work with EF but it throws an exception:

```
var c = ac.Communities.OrderBy(o => o.Posts.Count())
        .Skip(page*limit)
        .Take(limit)
        .Select(o => o.ToViewModel()).ToArray();
```

The `ToViewModel()` method from the `Community` model looks like this:

```
public CommunityModel ToViewModel()
{
    return new CommunityModel()
    {
        category = Category.Name,
        created = CreationTime,
        description = Description,
        id = Id,
        name = Name,
        ownerId = Owner.Id,
        postsCount = Posts.Count(),
        score = Posts.Sum(o => o.Likes - o.Unlikes),
        shortDescription = ShortDescription,
        subscribersCount = Subscribers.Count(),
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To rule out your `ToViewModel` method, pop a `.ToList()` in front of the `Select` and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: @Stuart That works, thanks! So, basically, the `List` is no longer an `IQueryable`so it doesn't try to translate this into SQL Queries for the database, right? That means it does all that in the memory, treating the `Community` class as an actual object, not a db entity, right?

Comment: That's correct, you are forcing an enumeration of the `IQueryable` at the point to use `ToList`, then the follow Linq methods are acting on an in memory collection and don't have to worry about translating to SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework cannot translate the methods you are using inside `ToViewModel`. Use `ToList()` to eagerly load the results, then map those instead, avoiding the need for EF to try to translate the SQL:

```
var c = ac.Communities.OrderBy(o => o.Posts.Count())
    .Skip(page*limit)
    .Take(limit)
    .ToList()
    .Select(o => o.ToViewModel()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because LINQ to Entities, try to convert `.ToViewModel` to an SQL query, which isn't recognized by the converter.

If there are not a lot of results being returned by `.Take`, then your best solution will be converting the `IQueryable` to `List` by changing it to the following.

```
var c = ac.Communities.OrderBy(o => o.Posts.Count())
        .Skip(page*limit)
        .Take(limit)
        .ToArray() // This will return a Community array
        .Select(o => o.ToViewModel()) // This is a IEnumerable<CommunityModel>
        .ToArray(); // This will cast // This is a cast for Community array
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm gonna use. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, though: 
accept
This is because LINQ to Entities, try to convert .ToViewModel to an SQL query, which isn't recognized by the converter.

If there are not a lot of results being returned by .Take, then your best solution will be converting the IQueryable to List by changing it to the following.... otherwise... ?